# Error : Object are not valid as a react child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am Trying to loop through the data coming from database, but react is giving me this error
[image]

i have tried by rendering the list in seperate componet still it doesnot work!,i am beginner to react ecosystem.
fetched data look like-
[image]

and my page code is this-

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './account.scss';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { selectCurrentUser } from '../../reducer/user/user.selectors';
import Order from '../../models/order';


const AccountPage = ({ currentUser }) =>{
const[orders,setOrders]=useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchFunc= async () =>{
        try{
            const response= await  fetch(`https://orders-6exxx.firebaseio.com/userorders/${currentUser.id}.json`);

            if(!response.ok){
                throw new Error('Something Went Wrong!');
            }
            const resData= await response.json();
            const loadedOrders=[];

            for(const key in resData){
                loadedOrders.push(
                    new Order(
                  key,
                  resData[key].cartItems,
                  resData[key].totalAmount,
                  new Date(resData[key].date)
                ));
            }
       setOrders(loadedOrders);
        }catch(err){
     throw err;
        }
    };

    fetchFunc();


},[currentUser]);

console.log(orders);

    return(
        <div className='account'>
        {orders&&orders.length ? (
            <div className='account__container'>



              {
                 orders.map(order =>(
                     <div className='account__containers__orders'>
                         <div className='account__containers__orders--date'>
                               {order.date}
                             </div>

                             {
                                 order.items.map(item => (
                                     <div className='account__containers__orders__item'>
                                          <div>{item.name}</div>
                                          <div>{item.quantity} x</div>
                                          <div>{item.price}</div>
                                     </div>
                                 ))
                             }

                          <div className='account__containers__orders--total'>
                              <span className='price--tag'>&#8377;</span> {order.totalAmount}
                             </div>

                </div>
                 ))
             }      

    </div>
        ) : (
            <div className='orders-loading'>
                No Orders
            </div>
        )}

   </div>
    );
};



const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    currentUser: selectCurrentUser
  });



  export default connect(
   mapStateToProps
  )(AccountPage);
```

single data is loading but when i try to print multiple data, it gives me this error

Comment: Remember to reduce your code to an [mcve], there's a lot of code here that doesn't contribute to the problem and are much better removed for the purpose of getting a good answer (as well as for you to understand the problem: almost always you discover the problem on your own when you starting reducing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store `new Date()` inside your orders state and it is treated ot be an object. In order to render it you can convert it to a string

```
{order.date.toString()}
```

or

```
{order.date.toDateString()}
```

Comment: oh yes, it showing that i can mark it in 4 minutes, i will definetly mark it